# how to use getContentResolver() in a separate class

Tags: java, android

I have a class which extends from broadcastReceiver and is giving me GPS coordinates. I want to show the serial number of the phone along with its coordinates.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

long time = 10 * 1000; 

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, time, minDistance, locationListener);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    String serialNumber = Build.SERIAL != Build.UNKNOWN ? Build.SERIAL :        Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);   // returns device id of phone              

    String Text = "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +" Longitude = " location.getLongitude(); 

        Toast.makeText(context, Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

      } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "SMS faild, please try again.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

}
```

In order to get the device serial number I'm using the following code, but it shows an error that getContentResolver() is undefined. I have searched solutions and tried getActivity() and getApplicationContext() but that is not working for me.

```
String serialNumber = Build.SERIAL != Build.UNKNOWN ? Build.SERIAL :       Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);   // returns device id of phone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `context` or 
        `context.getContentResolver();`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it should be:

```
context.getContentResolver()
```

because the `ContentResolver` belongs to the `Context`, and `Context` is passed through the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `Context` and call it with `context.getContentResolver().`

Answer (score 0):

just pass context from one class to another class 
use context.getContextResolver()